# Adjusting highlights, midtones and shadows in an image

Tags: image-processing

I can adjust the highlights in an image with

```
highlight[img_, brightness_, contrast_, gamma_, threshold_, colour_, cthreshold_] := 
ImageCompose[img, SetAlphaChannel[ImageAdjust[
 Blend[{img, colour}, cthreshold], {brightness, contrast, gamma}], 
 Binarize[img, threshold]]];


(* highlight[i, 0, .1, .5, .75, Yellow, .1]}}] *)
```

I have tried to use `ImageCompose` to change the midtones and shadows too, but am getting a little stuck. I'm trying to get MMA to ignore the highlight area when I adjust the midtones/shadows. I have tried different combinations of `ColorNegate@Binarize[img, threshold]`, but it gets complicated quickly.

I guess the problem reduces to create a threshold between 2 values, and then nest the function.

Is there an clean way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colour theory is probably wrong here, but I think a nice way to select the mids is to select pixel values with a "middle" luminance, right? We can do that by taking the L channel and thresholding it, them applying the resulting image as a mask.

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Girl3"}]
```

[image]

Now, we create our function to threshold the image. You may want to change this to a "softer" function - you can see some example in the `Threshold` documentation.

```
thresh[min_, max_] := Piecewise[{{#, min < # < max}}, 0] &
```

Now we create our mask, by applying our threshold to the luminance channel. Here we can vary what we might call our "midtones" - right now, I'm saying anything with a luminance value between .3 and .6 are what we want to keep. Of course, getting the highlights or shadows simply involves changing the arguments to `thres` (for example, shadows might be `thresh[0, 0.2]` and highlights `thresh[0.8, 1]`).

```
mask = Image@
  MapAt[thresh[.3, .6], ImageData[ColorSeparate[i, "L"]], {All, All}]
```

[image]

Finally, we composite our image, making our edits to the full image, then removing the masked section. I also `Blur` the mask here in order to get slightly less sharp artifacts.

```
ImageCompose[i, SetAlphaChannel[ImageAdjust[i, {0, .3}], Blur@mask]]
```

[image]

We can see that the background and shirt have become a bit brighter, but the dark hair and most of the face have remained the same. I suppose those would be what I might call the "midtones", but maybe there's a more precise definition that I ignored. You also may want to look into using the "V" of "HSV" (with `ColorSeparate[i, "V"]`, or some other channel of a different colour space.

Comment: Many thanks - sorry for the late response!